# Markov inequality with $a$ lower than mean

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality

In markov's inequality we have $P(X \geq a) \leq \displaystyle\frac{\mathbb{E}[X]}{a}$ but isn't it possible to have $a < \mathbb{E}[X]$ giving a probability lower or equal than a number greater than 1?

Comment: So what, the inequality still holds true

Comment: Yes i just wanted to confirm that it was no mistake on my part. Since i couldn't find any information on markov's inequality being only usefull if $a$ was greater than the mean i tought i might have interpreted the problem wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, and then the inequality is still true but trivial. Hence, the Markov inequality is only useful for $a > E[X]$.

Analogously, the [Chebyshev's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality#Statement) is only useful when the distance from the mean is greater than one standard deviation.